# Add larger attachments in an RDOMail

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm creating an RDOMail item programmatically. However when I try to add a large attachment (100 MB), it wont get added and no exception is also thrown. Is there a limitation in size of attachments being add ? if so, how to bypass this limitation ?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: There is no error. It just halts for sometime and the displaying mail item does not have any attachment

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: `Redemption.RDOMail rdoMailItem = destinationFolder.Items.Add();
            rdoMailItem.Body = "Something";
            rdoMailItem.To = "Something";
            rdoMailItem.Subject = "Something";
            rdoMailItem.Attachments.Add("File Temp location");
            File.Delete("File Temp Location");`

Comment: Do you ever call rdoMailItem.Save()?

Comment: Yes. once the attachements are being added , i call save method

Comment: If there are limitations in file extensions, I'm thinking that is what might causing the problem ?

Comment: Send an email to Redemption support at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/contact.htm and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: Hello, Did @DmitryStreblechenko solve your problem. ? 
Actually, I have the same problem and I can't find any solution. ??

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Yes. actually the attachments were being attached, some attachments were not showing due to outlook extension limitations. still the attachments were containing in the mail item.